# Trying to get username from one database and paste it with a message to another database

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm currently trying to set up a chat. It works fine on its own, however when I try and get the username from another database for a log in system I have instead of having people choose a username then and there, the system breaks down and doesn't upload the messages to the database. I get no errors.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "forum");
$mysqli2 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (isset($_GET['message']) && isset($_GET['username'])) {

    $user=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
    $message=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['message']);
    $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql="INSERT INTO forum(id, user, message, date) VALUES(0,'$user','$message','$date')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Forum</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Forum Messages:</h2>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM forum";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result2 = $mysqli2->query($sql2);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row2['username'].',  '.$row['date'].' <br>';
  echo $row['message'].'<br>';
  echo '------------------------ <br>';
}
?>


<form method="get" action="forum.php">
<p>Message:<br>
  <label for="message"></label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post message">
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone got an idea of why its not working?

Comment: You're always inserting with `id=0`? Is `id` autoincrement? You also might want to take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, I guess you get no errors because you don't look for them

Comment: Yes id is autoincrement

Comment: If `id` is autoinc you can skip it in the query I think, try `$sql="INSERT INTO forum(user, message, date) VALUES('$user','$message','$date')";`

Comment: Changing $sql to that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You get no errors because you're not checking for any. It's probable that the insert is failing. Your call to `query()` will return `FALSE` in this case, so you'll need to check for that.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO forum(user, message, date) VALUES('$user','$message','$date')";
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === false) {
    throw new Exception('Error performing insert: ' . $mysqli->error);
}
```

Also note, in this following code, you're not aborting, you just print the error message and then continue on with the script anyway:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Change the `echo` to a `throw` so the script stops.

And ideally, you want to use prepared statements instead of `real_escape_string()`. Something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO forum(user, message, date) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
if ($stmt === false) {
    // prepare failed
}
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_GET['username'], $_GET['message'], date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    // exec failed
}
```

Comment: Messages are still not getting sent to the database

Comment: What is `query()` returning?

Comment: It's returning nothing as far as I can see

Comment: Wrap the query in a var_dump(): `var_dump($mysqli->query($sql));`

Comment: Well when I added it to ```if (var_dump($mysqli->query($sql)) === false)``` nothing came up, but when I added it to ```$result = var_dump($mysqli->query($sql));``` it showed               object(mysqli_result)[3]
  public 'current_field' => int 0
  public 'field_count' => int 4
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'type' => int 0